# while loop inside while loop MySQL

Tags: php, mysqli

I have two tables in MySQL, one stores both have a main id key, but different details inside, for example:

```
table 1: | id | name | type |

table 2: | id | secondary id | more dateails |
```

The simplified code I'm using:

```
$status = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `table1`");

while($rows = $status->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)) 
{
    $id = $rows['id'];
    $conts_q = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `table2` WHERE id='$id'");
    $conts_numr = $conts_q->num_rows;

    if($conts_numr==0)
    {
        //Display empty
    }
    else
    {
        while($row2 = $conts_q->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH))
        {
            //Get details and display
        }
    }
}
```

If the second table has no contents, it shows it fine, but if it does, it shows all of the contents for each id instead of only the ones relevant for it, I cant seem to find what I'm doing wrong. If the code I posted is not sufficient I will post the full original code here.

Comment: [Time to learn about `JOIN` instead of making 2 needless loop specially one inside another. Example: `SELECT t1.name, t1.type, t2.details FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.referencedidfromtable1 WHERE t1.id = '$id'`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7877720/the-best-tutorial-on-joins-in-mysql)

Comment: Show some love to your server and use JOINs.

Comment: Please **indent your code** correctly. You're asking for help, make your post as readable as possible. I've done it for you this time :)

Comment: Thank you, ill will try the solution at once, appologize for the code

Comment: @durian also don't forget to use prepared statement as your current code is wide open to SQL injection. You're already using MySQLi make a bit more effort and learn prepared statement as well ;)

Comment: The thing is, I may have ids in table1 for which there are no values in table2, I still want to dispaly them but in a different way, while with join I only get the ones that exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was stated in the comments, the best way to get this data is to use a `JOIN`.

```
SELECT * FROM `table1` t1
INNER JOIN `table2` t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
```

You may need to massage the returned columns and such as well.